# Fetching all Git repositories in the background

Tags: cron, git

I'm thinking about setting up a cronjob for fetching all my repositories every once in a while, to have the current status ready in case I'm offline. Something like the following (wrapped for better readability):

```
find $HOME -name .git -type d -printf "%h\0" |
  parallel --gnu -0 --delay 0.2 --jobs 100 --progress \
  'cd {}; git fetch --all --quiet'
```

I don't really care what happens if the fetch fails -- it might succeed the next time. Perhaps error output could be logged. My questions are:

- What if the background process fetches into a Git repository while I'm committing to it?
- Can you recommend other switches to `parallel` to make this really fail-safe?

Comment: Given that git is for multi-user collaboration and it was written by Linus... I can't imagine there isn't a git-lock somewhere.  It would require testing to find out though.

Comment: @hbdgaf Yes it does, it creates `.git/index.lock`. But I don't think the lock file is created when using fetch. Probably because `fetch --all` is harmless and doesn't do any modification to your local tree whatsoever.

Comment: You could clone every repository locally (i.e. have one clone for this job to work on and another for you to work on)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been fetching my local Git repos in the background for two years now, without any sign of trouble. Currently, crontab contains something like

```
savelog -n -c 400 ~/log/git-fetch.log
find ~/git -type d -execdir [ -d '{}/.git' ]  \; -print -prune |
    parallel --gnu --keep-order \
    "date; echo {}; cd {}; git fetch --all --verbose" \
    >> ~/log/git-fetch.log 2>&1
```

(but in one line).

Comment: Is this the final script you used or there is an update? thanks

Comment: Pasted final version.